# Any virtual space for writting code

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, virtual-machine

Like we have intellij and eclipse, do we have anything similar in virtual, where I don't have to open anything on my laptop and directly login in into another environtment?

Answer (score 0):

Web-based cloud IDEs could suit you well. I have experience with [Cloud9](https://c9.io/). Alternatives are [Eclipse Orion](https://orionhub.org/), [Nitrous](https://www.nitrous.io/), [ShiftEdit](https://shiftedit.net/), [ICEcoder](https://icecoder.net/), [Codiad](http://codiad.com/), [Codeanywhere](https://codeanywhere.com/) or [Ideone](http://ideone.com/).